# Apple Pay token's transaction amount is incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, applepay

Apple Pay token contains wrong transactionAmount info. E.g if the transaction amount is $1.10, on iOS device, Apple Pay screen stills show correct amount but paymentToken returns 110 when decrypted

I used this library to decrypt Apple Pay token using my own public-private key pair

https://github.com/sidimansourjs/applepay-token

My sample code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
 @IBAction func payBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        do {
            let paymentItem = PKPaymentSummaryItem.init(label: "Test item", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: 1.10))
            let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.amex, .discover, .masterCard, .visa]

            if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {

                let request = PKPaymentRequest()
                request.currencyCode = "SGD" // 1
                request.countryCode = "SG" // 2
                request.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.xxxxx" // 3
                request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS // 4
                request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks // 5
                request.paymentSummaryItems = [paymentItem] // 6

                guard let paymentVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) else {
                    displayDefaultAlert(title: "Error", message: "Unable to present Apple Pay authorization.")
                    return
                }

                paymentVC.delegate = self
                self.present(paymentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                displayDefaultAlert(title: "Error", message: "Unable to make Apple Pay transaction.")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}

extension ViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {

        let token = String(data: payment.token.paymentData, encoding: .utf8)
        let utf8str = token!.data(using: .utf8)

        if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString()
        {
            print("Encoded:  \(base64Encoded)")

            //Send token to backend server to decrypt
        }
    }
}
```

I discovered this when try to make payment request to Adyen (a payment gateway). Request must contain both `amount` field and `paymentToken` field but was never successful because amount in `amount` and `paymentToken` is mis-matched. Then I tried `amount` 110 instead of 1.10 then request was success, but ironically in Adyen dashboard somehow it still understood transaction amount was $1.10

I expected `transactionAmount` in Apple Pay token to be 1.10

Please help to explain why there's this difference in Apple Pay amount shown on device and in token

Comment: Payment processors require the currency’s smallest unit, so 110 = 1.10

Comment: Do you have any reference for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer as suggested by @Don
Singapore Dollar SGD's smallest unit is cent, which is 1/100 of a dollar. Therefore I need to convert dollar amount into cent integer by multiply with 100. Then, use this value when send over to Adyen